# Can we speed-up CPU intensive tasks in java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Task like finding factorial of 2000 where using BigInteger is a CPU-intensive task, is there anyway to speed-up such processes?

Ex: finding 2000!
Since it is a single task only, i think there is no need of thread here( as running this program or running this task in a thread both has to perform such CPU-intensive things).

I've heard that Java 7 introduced a new parallel mechanism for compute intensive tasks.
So, how do i perform this kind of things in it?

Comment: a tutorial for the new parallel mechanism: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: First of all: Don't use BigInteger for multiplying large numbers. It's using a naive multiply algorithm which is O(n^2) instead of karatsuba which would be O(n log n).

Comment: @Voo Tiny factual correction: Karatsuba is `O(n^1.585)`. FFT is the one that gets near `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @Mysticial Ups yes you're absolutely right, mea culpa. Still a good bit better than n^2 but that's not an excuse to get that wrong :( (and no I didn't think of FFTs, just a stupid mistake)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A factorial could be easily split to two tasks with a final merge. This is some kind of a map-reduce, if you like.

Example:

```
9! = (7*5*3*1) * (8*6*4*2)
```

So you can have two tasks.

This can be generalized into any amount of parallel tasks.

This solution has nothing to do with Java in specific, it's about converting "regular" solutions to parallel ones.

Comment: This has the additional advantage that we're multiplying much smaller numbers for most of the time which is MUCH faster even if you don't parallelize it. Good idea to split the sequential tasks given to each CPU up further using the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to simply submit a query to WolframAlpha, and get back an approximate answer within a fraction of a second ([at least for 2,000!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2000!), or even [10,000,000,000!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000000000!)), which, if you only need an approximation for large factorials, will probably be more than enough.

Here's a wikipedia article on the [challenges around calculating large factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Computation) by yourself, some of which you've already discovered.

What you'll really want to do is try to reduce the total amount of work that needs to be done. The simplest way to do this is to store the results in a table, and do a lookup. The table to contain all these values can be quite large, but that's one method if storage isn't a limitation in your situation.

Simply trying to parallelize it won't save you on CPU (unless you're calculating an approximation, as opposed to the precise number), because you're doing to same amount of total work, but spreading it out. Also, parallelizing anything involves some overhead (inter-thread/inter-process communication, distributed memory if the problem space is large enough, all kinds of things). The places where parallelizing any algorithm is a big win, is when you can successfully split up the problem into smaller chunks, and spread those chunks out efficiently enough so that the time to...

- send the chunks out out
- have the chunks calculated
- send the results back
- combine the results

...is less costly (as measured in time, money, storage, electricity, or whatever your limited resource is) than doing it series, and/or that it provides some value (time, money, storage, etc. **saved**) so that it effectively makes up for the cost.